# How can I enable/disable "Translucent Selection Rectangle" programmatically?

Tags: winapi, registry

The setting "Translucent Selection Rectangle" can be set in the registry using

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\ListviewAlphaSelect
```

however, the Windows Explorer will not change its behaviour without some kind of "refresh" which I don't know how to invoke.

The `SystemParametersInfo` function also does not seem to offer this functionality.

Does anyone know how I can adjust this UI setting programmatically?